# Lithium side effects (kidney)

Tags: medications, side-effects, mental-health, renal, lithium

Lithium (taken as a mood stabilizer) can lead to renal problems in patients, especially those taking it long-term.

How prevalent are these side effects and how are they managed - for example, stopping to take lithium, taking other medication alongside lithium?

Answer (score 2):

[The Impact Of Long-Term Lithium Treatment On Renal Function In An Outpatient Population](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2516429/)

> Lithium is known to affect renal concentrating ability, and
> lithium-induced polyuria is not uncommon, estimated to affect
> approximately 20% of patients, but this is rarely clinically
> significant. It is less clear, however, whether or not the protracted
> use of lithium can cause progressive deterioration in renal function,
> culminating in renal failure

[How can I avoid kidney damage due to lithium?](https://www.kidney.org/atoz/content/lithium)

> 1. Avoid levels of lithium that are toxic
> 2. Check blood levels of lithium to see if you are taking the lowest amount that still works for you
> 3. Check creatinine every year. Get medical help if your creatinine level stays above 1.6 mg/dl.
> 4. If possible, take lithium once a day.

***Some of these are interventions that your health care provider would utilize. So make sure you follow up with your healthcare provider.***

[Lithium Nephropathy](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/242772-overview)

> Evidence of chronic renal disease is an indication for discontinuation
> of the drug being administered and for consideration of alternative
> medications for treatment of the patient's psychiatric disorder.

[Treatments:](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/242772-treatment)

Polyuria --> Thiazide Diuretics & NSAIDs

Hypovolemia --> Parenteral Fluids

Dialysis may be indicated

The ICU may be indicated

Comment: @YviDe Those links work for me. Do they still produce errors for you?